# Adding a column in front of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Now I want to add a column of all ones in front of it to get:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 7, 8, 9]])
```

I saw many posts pertaining to my question, but none of them could solve my problem.  I tried `np.concatenate` `np.append` `np.hstack` but unfortunately none of them worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `np.concatenate`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                    [4, 5, 6],
                    [7, 8, 9]])

>>> np.concatenate((np.array([0,0,0])[:, np.newaxis], arr), axis=1)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 7, 8, 9]])
```

But `hstack` works too:

```
>>> np.hstack((np.array([0,0,0])[:, np.newaxis], arr))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 7, 8, 9]])
```

The only "tricky" part is that both arrays must have the same number of dimensions, that's why I added the `[:, np.newaxis]` - which adds a new dimension.

How to change the zeros to ones is left as an (easy) exercise :-)

If you want to prepend a 2D array you have to drop the `[:, np.newaxis]` part:

```
np.concatenate((np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int), arr), axis=1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Another nice way of including an extra dimension in situations like this is by indexing with `None`:

`np.array([0,0,0])[:, None]`

Comment: @kiliantics `np.newaxis` is just an alias for `None`, see for example `None is np.newaxis = True`. But I think it's a bit more explicit and thus preferrable when answering questions for people learning numpy. But nevertheless thank you for the comment, it might help future visitors +1

Comment: @MSeifert, your solution worked fine. But when I try to generalize it gives me an error:
  `np.concatenate((np.ones((3, 3))[:, np.newaxis], arr), axis=1)`
give me the error:
**ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions**

Comment: @BishwajitPurkaystha If you want to prepend a 2D array then just drop the `[:, np.newaxis]` part.

Comment: It would be better if you edit your answer for generalization for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this way:

```
ones = np.ones((3,1)) #3 is a number of rows in your array.   
new_array = np.hstack((ones,arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

vstack behaves a bit more nicely without having to worry about new axes, though MSeifert's answer is probably more correct:

```
p = np.array([1,1,1])
q = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

np.vstack((p,q.T)).T
```